# vuejs orderby property value in computed returning 9 items

Tags: vue.js

i have an array of objects(from a getter).I return 9 items using `slice(9 * this.page)` to display them in a 3x3 grid.The objects have a status property that changes.

What im looking for is a filter that sorts the array/getter so the items with status === 'OK' are in front, then with status === 'inProgress', so on.Nothing ive tried has worked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your status values from Strings to Numbers, like this:

```
computed:
{
  objectList()
  {
    const statValues = [
      'OK',
      'inProgress',
      'Completed',
    ];
    // we need 2 "slice()" - first one is because "sort()" will otherwise modify the list (which is an unwanted side effect for a computed property)
    // the other "slice()" is the real one that will return the 9 items for the current "page"
    return this.list.slice().sort((a, b) =>
    {
      const statA = statValues.indexOf(a.status);
      const statB = statValues.indexOf(b.status);
      return statA - statB;
    }).slice(9 * this.page);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, as otherwise it is depending on what kind of statuses you actually make and how would one compare them.

Comment: Nice answer only slicing had to happen after as that gets 9 unsorted items and then sorts them.I did try something like that with a getter having every type of status i needed but couldnt figure it out